# How can type-narrowing differ between assignment via ternary expressions and if-else statements?

Tags: typescript, types

It appears that the type checker is typing `m` in `print()` differently depending on if `m` was assigned via a ternary expression or via an if-else statement. What is the difference between the first line in the `print()` function and the commented code below that line?

```js
interface Measurement {
  unit: string;
}

interface ComputedMeasurement extends Measurement {
  compute: (n: number) => number;
}

const measurements = {
  'Vitamin D': {
    unit: 'mcg',
  },
};

const computedMeasurements = {
  'Vitamin D (IU)': {
    unit: 'IU',
    compute: (n: number) => n / 0.025,
  },
};

type MeasurementKey = keyof typeof measurements;
type ComputedMeasurementKey = keyof typeof computedMeasurements;

const isMeasurementKey = (k: string): k is MeasurementKey =>
  k in measurements;

function print(key: MeasurementKey | ComputedMeasurementKey, amount: number): string {
  const m = isMeasurementKey(key) ? measurements[key] : computedMeasurements[key];
  // *** Replacing the above line with the below lines eliminates the below error. ***
  // let m: Measurement | ComputedMeasurement;
  // if (isMeasurementKey(key)) {
  //   m = measurements[key];
  // } else {
  //   m = computedMeasurements[key];
  // }

  if ('compute' in m) {
    // Error: Property 'compute' does not exist on type '{ unit: string; }'.
    return `${m.compute(amount)} ${m.unit}`;
  }
  return `${amount} ${m.unit}`;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLITgZwK5QgWwnGQG8BYAKGWWxGDAC5lMwpQBzAbkoF9LLQkWIhQBhAPb4ADtkgATdFlwEiYZBAAekEHMxoMOPIWLkqyBJJmQmAChBMQ2fACNoASmQBeAHzJHL6G4KPgpKCxAWZEIlI1U9T1JKagByADV6OHxQZAARZKZTampaeiZk-AR2ZIAaJOQeWuCgsPEItQtpWQgFA2VjMHjEszSMrJBc5BsASQBVN3yhopo6RmRk2Zq66g6rCFt7PydXKA8fP2QAemQABgA6a4AmAFZG6gbeZoowAE8pFEVDCpwABpCDfLzIADWYPEMGQPz+sKivVi4EwQQRYksXR6MSBYFB4IS0O+SMxSJ2OIBfTin3CkWAmGpqIJYIhNkhTBYbBA7DcTEhyEZ+jx-UJXm8dUF2WigP66P4FBgtAQYGArWQUh5YA5YKYzPx4oAPsgJJ15AaxWDqshMuJaKt-Md+cxWBxFuZWpF8BDGZbVITdd8PAB+ZGiuIAbRJAF1kExKRaUfjMNGwTGgtQLlcAFR55AAJQgUgANoh3WAABYoODOcQANxQJdAKAA7vRK-Dq8hXCXxK3kM2QBA9BBm2M4JA9FWUL3++ooFBxFBbsg8zm6tnBxA1Ph9cn+sgTWbdri5apM5crsA4TY-QeA2Cg24PIUr0UfQlZTS0WnvhnNyuHh1BLTAUDfLdqE-T1zW6f1f1jS8txCOob0mZJEwgZIhXGfBXy2ZA8DAXBxgAAwAEhIfBbkwmw7QdNxgMo6iSjAHhSMvEJqCIkjkAokh6PAJiqNuVj2KCHggA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, the difference is that the let declaration followed by the if-then-else assignments keeps the union type `Measurement | ComputedMeasurement` for `m` (which is expected behavior), but the conditional expression narrows the type to `Measurement`, which triggers the type error.

Turns out this is the intended behavior for conditional expressions where one alternative is a subtype of the other, as is explained in this closed [TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46449). One of the comments mentions that the subtype reduction can sometimes be a little unfortunate, and your example is one of these cases.

If you declare `measurements` and `computedMeasurements` as readonly objects with `as const`, you can use the conditional expression without any errors, as
the computed measurement will no longer be a subtype of the measurement:

```
const measurements = {
  'Vitamin D': {
    unit: 'mcg',
  },
} as const;

const computedMeasurements = {
  'Vitamin D (IU)': {
    unit: 'IU',
    compute: (n: number) => n / 0.025,
  },
} as const;
```

But you can also just use the if-then-else assignments.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLITgZwK5QgWwnGQG8BYAKGWWxGDAC5lMwpQBzAbkoF9LLQkWIhQBhAPb4ADtkgATdFlwEiYZBAAekEHMxoMOPIWLkqyBJJmQmAChBMQ2fACNoASmQBeAHzJHL6G4KPgpKCxAWZEIlI1U9T1JKagByADV6OHxQZAARZKZTampaeiZk-AR2ZIAaJOQeWuDkLHNxCLAgsLbIi2lZCAUDZWMweMSzNIyskFzkGwBJAFU3fPGimjpGZGSlmrrqXqsIW3s-J1coDx8-ZAB6ZAAGADoHgCYAVkbqBt5mvXCWJ0KGAAJ5SFCKQwqcAAaQgIK8yAA1vDxDBkKDwWiokNYuBMEFMWJLP1BjFoWA4QiEiiQdiidjDqTIcM4kCAWpgJgWXjKfDETYkUwWGwQOw3EwkcgufpySMqV5vHUpdlolCRgT%20BQYLQEGBgG1kFJRWBBfCmDyKQqAD7ICR9eSW%20Xw6rNfDiWhbfwXCXMVgcNatdpRRFcp2qKlmkEeAD8OLlcQA2rSALrIJhMx24imYZPwlNA6jAdE2ZKZiDJaUzfAeQpFPBgXAzAAGABISPgnuWbJkPeA3DxkO3OyUwDxm0FvnUG03kG2SL3PYPh09R%20OgiEgA)

Comment: Thanks for finding that issue. I'll also add that, according to a comment in that issue, asserting the type of the ternary expression with `as Measurement | ComputedMeasurement` works as well.

Comment: Ah yes, I left it out because of the reduced type safety. In some cases type assertions are fine, but if there's a typed way to avoid them I would generally go for that. Future extensions and refactorings of the code become a lot more fragile when there are assertions involved.